# How to parse file to include lines between characters in perl?

Tags: regex, perl

How to print the lines between the +s including +s using perl from a file? I have these lines in a file.

```
blah blah
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
this line should be included.
this line should be included too.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
abcd  100101001010
```

desired output:

```
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
this line should be included.
this line should be included too.
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
```

Comment: Set a boolean flag to true when you identify the first line of pluses.  Flip it back to false when you reach the second line of pluses.  Only output when the flag is true.

Comment: This is not cleanly solvable with regexes, I would rather advise using the strategy suggested by Robert Harvey too. Regexes are powerful for building lexers, getting lexical units, but this would be too complicated to solve with regexes IMHO.

Comment: I meant this problem is similar to extracting block comments for example, it is more a grammatical parser task than a simple lexer task.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the range operator `...` like so:

```
perl -nlwe 'print if /^\++$/ ... /^\++$/' input.txt
```

The three-dot range operator has a special feature that makes it possible to use here. From [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators)

> [The "two-dot" ".." operator] can test the right operand and become false on the same evaluation it became true (as in awk), but it still returns true once. If you don't want it to test the right operand until the next evaluation, as in sed, just use three dots ("...") instead of two. In all other regards, "..." behaves just like ".." does.

Comment: pure genius!!! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
while(<>){
    print if /^\++$/ .. /^\++$/;
}
```

Comment: thanks. almost worked.